# Type alias optimization skipping implicit conversion in Scala?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I have the following code:

```
  type RString = String

  implicit def stringToRString(s:String):RString = s.reverse

  val s = "The Force Awakens"
  val r:RString = s

  println(r)
```

I kind of expected `r` to be the reverse of `s` but it is equal to `s`. 
Is this the scala compiler taking a shortcut as `RString` is an alias of `String` so the implicit conversion is never called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want an alias, but a marker trait or tag for reversed strings.

```
scala> trait Reversed
defined trait Reversed

scala> def cv(s: String): String with Reversed =
     | s.reverse.asInstanceOf[String with Reversed]
cv: (s: String)String with Reversed

scala> implicit def cv(s: String): String with Reversed =
     | s.reverse.asInstanceOf[String with Reversed]
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
cv: (s: String)String with Reversed

scala> val r: String with Reversed = "hi"
r: String with Reversed = ih
```

Answer (score 5):

A type alias does not introduce a *new* type, it's an *alias*. You can replace left and right hand side. Thus `r: RString` is the same as `r: String`, and therefore no conversion is required.

You would need something like this:

```
object RString {
  // allow RString to be used as a String
  implicit def toString(r: RString): String = r.toString
}
implicit class RString(val peer: String) extends AnyVal {
  override def toString = peer.reverse
}

val s = "The Force Awakens"
val r: RString = s  // "snekawA ecroF ehT"
```

That is, `RString` is a new type, a value class that reverses the string.

Comment: `AnyVal` doesn't avert allocation here.

Comment: why isn't it averted?

Comment: @som-snytt perhaps you are right; not sure. One could use [unboxed tagged types](http://etorreborre.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/practical-uses-for-unboxed-tagged-types.html) for that I guess.

Comment: No, I was wrong. It invokes `RString$.toString$extension` with the underlying value as usual. I thought it would box for `toString` for some reason, but now that I am at a computer, I am disabused.